# Multi Line Excel VBA User Form Txt Box

Tags: excel, vba, windows, text, userform

I am making a user form in Excel in order to convert F values to C Values by the integer of the range specified. I have the program working correctly as it is quite simple, but I cannot seem to get the txt box on the user form to display anything but the last recorded results. How can I get each of the integer values to print in the txt box on the user form similar to the way it prints with the debug print command? I have attached a few pictures illustrating the issue.

Also please excuse the spelling issues. I was quickly trying to get the code working before I worked on formatting.

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eABz.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoGAT.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOgBR.png)
```

I have tried using different commands like vbNewLine and vbCrLf but nothing seems to work. When the txt Box is smaller, the scroll wheel functions, so I know it cannot be an issue with the TXT box.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. in my code, I changed the TxtR = ***** to be txtR = txtR + ***New information*** and it works as expected. Thanks!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim max As Integer
Dim min As Integer
Dim Cel As Single

max = Val(txtMax.Value)
min = Val(txtMin.Value)

For i = min To max
    Cel = (i - 32) * 5 / 9
    txtR = txtR & i & "F   " & Cel & "C" & vbCrLf
Next i
End Sub
```